# Is it good practice to use two image sets for different devices using media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make a photography resume type website and came across this issue that using landscape images and making it responsible for mobile devices isn't good as some better details gets lost in it vise versa for desktop and portrait. I was wondering to have to image asset for mobile devices and desktops and displaying them accordingly with media queries

Comment: It is good practice. You want to use the <picture> tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: @TJBlackman Thanks for the info. Although it would be hard to implement this since i used the background image property it's still new info for me. Wouldn't the loading of both assets be stressing the load time of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

> yes

Why?

> because on smaller screens you have different orientation, eg. not
> landscape. Also you dont need to spend resources loading an image with
> x amount of pixels when the smaller screen can only display y amount.
> Also when exceeding a Z amount of pixels the eye will not be able to
> tell the difference, thereby smaller images = good.

also take a look at this link for image best practices

> https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization